# Returning directory contents over SMB, subprocess, and OS

Tags: python, subprocess, contextmanager

I'm trying to connect over SMB, using the subprocess command, to establish a connection to a remote directory. Once the connection is established, I want to list the contents of the directory. Here is the code:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
from directory import getFileContents
from os import walk

def mount(remote_dir, local_dir):
    retcode = subprocess.call(["/sbin/mount", "-t", "smbfs", remote_dir, local_dir])

def unmount(local_dir):
    retcode = subprocess.call(["/sbin/umount", local_dir])

def getFileContents(directory):
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory):
        f.extend(filenames)
        break
    return f

mount('//Guest@192.168.1.167/Pictures', 'Pictures')

a = getFileContents('/Volumes/Pictures')
print(a)

input("Press any key to unmount: ")


unmount('Pictures')
```

The code references an import from a separate function, which is supposed to list the contents of a directory:

```
from os import walk


def getFileContents(directory):
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory):
        f.extend(filenames)
        break
    return f
```

I'm expecting this to return the file contents of the folder '/Volumes/Pictures', which is a directory on the remote computer, but, when just printing the contents of 'a', outside of the for loop, I'm returning back an empty list. I'm working in OSX, I believe the issue might lie somewhere in how my file paths are being structured, as the ability to mount a directory seems to pass or fail on the basis of which directory I execute the code from. When I run the following in the python terminal:

```
>>>from os import walk


>>>def getFileContents(directory):
    ...f = []
    ...for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory):
        ...f.extend(filenames)
        ...break
    ...return f
a = getFileContents('/Volumes/Pictures')
print(a)
```

I can get back a listing of the directory contents, but not when doing the SMB connection via the subprocess. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in how I was looking at the 'local_dir' portion of the above code. The above code mounts the contents of the remote directory into a local directory. So, when I change my code to the following:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
from directory import getFileContents
from os import walk

def mount(remote_dir, local_dir):
    retcode = subprocess.call(["/sbin/mount", "-t", "smbfs", remote_dir, local_dir])

def unmount(local_dir):
    retcode = subprocess.call(["/sbin/umount", local_dir])

def getFileContents(directory):
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(directory):
        f.extend(filenames)
        break
    return f

mount('//Guest@192.168.1.167/Pictures', '/Users/ParanoidPenguin/smb')

a = getFileContents('/Users/ParanoidPenguin/smb')
print(a)

input("Press any key to unmount: ")


unmount('/Users/ParanoidPenguin/smb')
```

I'm able to resolve the issue. In this case, the contents of the remote 'Pictures' folder, are going to show in the local directory '/Users/ParanoidPenguin/smb'.